Text above equal sign in an align or gather environments is misplaced with babel?
I write my homework in Hebrew using babel and lualatex. I encountered a weird bug that if I put an \eqref above something inside an align or gather environment in Hebrew, then the reference moves to the wrong spot. Here's the code I was playing with:
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% Font setup
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Miriam CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{tt}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\babelfont{david}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{David CLM}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:he-pythagoras}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
לפי משוואה
\eqref{eq:he-pythagoras}
נסיק כי
\begin{align*}
c^4 \overset{\eqref{eq:he-pythagoras}}{=} (a^2 + b^2)^2
\end{align*}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:en-pythagoras}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
According to equation \eqref{eq:en-pythagoras}, we can conclude that:
\begin{align*}
    c^4 \overset{\eqref{eq:en-pythagoras}}{=} (a^2 + b^2)^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}

which produces:

As you can see, the reference above the equal sign in the Hebrew version is in the completely wrong spot. I have searched everywhere online to find a solution and couldn't find anything. All I managed to find was a weird workaround that only works on Overleaf and not my local machine for some reason. Can someone please help me solve this issue?

The problem here is babel patches an internal macro in some amsmath environments to correctly align the tag. \eqref uses this macro, in its original form in the text, but in the context of you MWE the modified form is the active one. How to catch the correct version to be used? I’m not still sure, but the following macro should work:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\exref}[1]{{%
  \let\bbl@ams@lap\relax
  \eqref{#1}}}
\makeatother


It worked. I will open an issue on babel's repo to report that.
